# create a rectangle by coloring cells automatically in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wondering is there is a simple function in Excel to automatically modify a range of cells (color outline and cell values)

My objective is to create a shape like below using only excel cell ;

X and Y being the height and width of a rectangle, and the external cell having a different color/label than the inside

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have office 365 put this in D2:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(B2,B3))
```

Then we will need two Conditional Formatting Rules:

```
=AND(OR(D1<=$B$3,D1>$B$2*$B$3-$B$3,MOD(D1,$B$3)=1,MOD(D1,$B$3)=0),D1<>"")
```

and

```
=ISNUMBER(D1)
```

The first is the border and second the inner part.

Make sure the Applies To: is full columns starting in D and ending with the last column possible.

Make sure that the Stop if True is marked on the first one.

[image]

---

Without Office 365 put this in D2:

```
=IF(OR(COLUMN(A$1)>$B$2,ROW($ZZ1)>$B$3),"",MIN(ROW($ZZ1),$B$3)-1+((MIN(COLUMN(A$1),$B$2)-1)*$B$3)+1)
```

And copy/drag over as many columns as there possibly will be and down as many rows as there possibly will be.  I drug it down 35 rows and over 20 columns.

And use the same conditional formatting rules as above:

[image]

Comment: I honestly thought this would be pretty cumbersome with CF... well done.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have Office 365, hence I do not have the =SEQUENCE function :-( 
But that what definitely what I was looking for...

Is there any other function I could look at ?

Comment: @ScottCraner Many thanks for your help, it is indeed what I need

Comment: @Gil please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.